# Seeding a payment history table with values for each BusinessEntityID in AdventureWorks2012

Tags: t-sql, cursor, seeding

I'm trying to seed a table with values using a cursor, I have come across a stubborn bug: *(0 row(s) affected) Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 43 String or binary data would be truncated.* The line the debugger is referencing is:
*SET @r = CAST(@p10 AS DECIMAL) * @m * 10.0*. I have debugged many mistakes so far, but stuck on this one. Any thoughts are appreciated! :)

```
    USE [AdventureWorks2012]
    GO
    DECLARE @p1 integer     --ID
    DECLARE @p2 nchar       --Job title
    DECLARE @p3 datetime    --DOB
    DECLARE @p4 nchar       --Rate
    DECLARE @p5 nchar       --Freq
    DECLARE @p6 date        --Start date
    DECLARE @p7 time        --Time start
    DECLARE @p8 time        --Time end
    DECLARE @p9 nchar       --Shift name
    DECLARE @p10 integer    --Hours

    DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
    SELECT BusinessEntityID, 
        JobTitle, 
        BirthDate,
        Rate,
        PayFrequency,
        StartDate,
        WorkStart,
        WorkEnd,
        ShiftName,
        ShiftHours
    FROM HumanResources.vPaymentIntelligence
    WHERE PayFrequency = 'Biweekly';
OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c
INTO @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @d date
    DECLARE @r decimal = 0.0
    DECLARE @m decimal = 1.0

    IF(@p9 = 'Evening')
        SET @m = 1.10
    ELSE IF(@p9 = 'Night')
        SET @m = 1.25

    SET @d = DATEADD(day, +14, @p6)
    SET @r = CAST(@p10 AS DECIMAL) * @m * 10.0

    INSERT INTO HumanResources.aPaymentHistory
    VALUES ('name', @r, @d, NULL, NULL, @p1, CONCAT('PAY:', CAST(@p1 AS nchar), '01'));
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    THROW
END CATCH
END
CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
```

**EDIT:** Definition of the HumanResources.aPaymentHistory table:

```
    GO
    --This table holds transactions between AB and it's employees.
    DROP TABLE AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.aPaymentHistory;
    CREATE TABLE AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.aPaymentHistory(
      Employee nchar NOT NULL,
      Amount money NOT NULL,
      Payday smalldatetime NOT NULL,
      Currency nvarchar(3) DEFAULT 'USD',
      Rate float DEFAULT '1',

      BusinessEntityID integer FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES       AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee (BusinessEntityID) NOT NULL,
 PaymentID nchar PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
 );
 GO
```

Comment: I added: 'FETCH NEXT FROM c' to line 51. Same error.

Comment: I have isolated the problem to the INSERT statement: INSERT INTO HumanResources.aPaymentHistory
  VALUES ('name', CAST(@r AS money), @d, NULL, NULL, @p1, CONCAT('PAY:', CAST(@p1 AS nchar), ':01'));